# What is this object seen in Mos Eisley spaceport?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, a-new-hope, object-identification

[image]

[image]

This object can be seen in Mos Eisley spaceport in *Star Wars: Episode IV*.

I’ve always wondered what its purpose is. Do we know?

Comment: a giant BB-8 head? ;)

Comment: @RedCaio - Jar Jar's tomb.

Comment: It's an incubator for scum and villainy.  That's how Mos Eisley got to be so wretched.

Comment: I remember those; that's where you stick your kid so you can go get drunk.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is a [9000 Z001 landspeeder](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/9000_Z001_landspeeder)

Per wookieepedia

> The 9000 Z001 landspeeder was a Ubrikkian model commonly used around
>   the time of the Battle of Yavin. It was modified from the 9000
>   landspeeder, which had been aimed at Ugor customers but had flopped.

---

At the time of filming, the ship was simply labelled (in the construction blueprints) as "Fourth Speeder". The tag "***9000 Z001***" seems to have been added later as a retcon.

[image]

[image]

The [Star Wars Galaxy Guide #7 (Mos Eisley)](http://www.baykock.com/archivos/starwars/Star_Wars_-_D6_-_Official_Supplement_-_Galaxy_Guide_07_-_Mos_Eisley_-_WEG40069_-_02.pdf) RPG sourcebook also offers the following non-canon info;

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure "9000" and "Z001" are not-so-subtle nods to the fact that this thing looks a lot like the EVA pods from *2001:  A Space Odyssey*.  The Z001 part is basically "2001", the 9000 is a tip of the hat to HAL 9000.

Comment: @WadCheber - Yup. And Ubrickkian = Kubrickian.

Comment: Crap.  Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: The pilot http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/7/79/Ugor.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20091203192414

Comment: @Hack-R - Well, ain't he a pretty fella?

Comment: Reminds me a little of the Capsule Corp. vehicles from Dragonball Z http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/c/c7/GokuShip1.png/revision/latest?cb=20110521021844

Comment: I used to own quite a few of that SWCCG card. +1 for citing that picture, though I don't think it's technically canon.

Comment: @ender - I believe most of them were based on entries from the (also non-canon) Star Wars Encyclopedia

Comment: I'd like to see this fly !

Comment: @Max - [Your merest whim is my most ardent desire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksOqb.gif)

Answer (score 6):

From the old [newspaper comic strips](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/9000_Z001_landspeeder#Behind_the_scenes), it appears to be a "low life droid."

[image]

Comment: Although this is interesting, it doesn't really explain much about this object. Even from the earliest design stages it was designated as a speeder, rather than a droid.